# Facing Problem in sending data to the HTTP using formData

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I am working angular 8 
Where I am trying to submit form via **Post** method by Using **FormData**

**Problem that I am getting is**

- **FormData is not able to send Data to the server** via post method
- in **response** I am getting Failure in submitting Form

### Let me Explain all the fields that I am sending

1. CustomerName ---Details--->  (**type** : string)
2. package_list_id ---Details--->   (**type** : array) , (**Default-value** - [0])
3. package_type_id ---Details--->  (**type** : array)  , (**Default-value** - [0])
4. budget  ---Details--->  (**type** : array) , (**Default-value** - [0])
5. is_manual---Details--->  (**type** : array) , (**Default-value** -[0])
6. UploadedFile  ---Details---> (**type** : array)

**Data I am sending in the format**

```
 let package_list_id = [0]
   let package_type_id = [0]
   let budget = [0]
   let is_manual = [0]
   let file = ['xyz.pdf']
      formData.append('CustomerName' , this.CustomerName); 
      formData.append('package_list_id', JSON.stringify(this.PacageListArray));
     formData.append('package_type_id', JSON.stringify(this.PackageArray));
      formData.append('budget', JSON.stringify(this.customPayArr));
      formData.append('is_manual', JSON.stringify(this.CheckAutoPayArr));
      formData.append('file', this.files);
```

When I consoled these FormData Using code

```
formData.forEach(result => console.log(result));
```

I am getting **Result**

- Tom Cruze
- [12]
- **noData**(blank)
- **noData**(blank)
- **noData**(blank)
- **noData**(blank)

**

> Problem is

**

> **FormData is  Only Reading first Array** (package_list_id) , **Next array it does not read**(package_type_id , budget , is_manual , file) , It is sending blank data for other arrays except while sending data to
>   server , Just wanted to inform Value is present before set in formData

**I am sharing my code**

.TS

```
  onSubmit() {

 let package_list_id = [0]
       let package_type_id = [0]
       let budget = [0]
       let is_manual = [0]
       let file = ['xyz.pdf']

        formData.append('CustomerName' , this.CustomerName); 
          formData.append('package_list_id', JSON.stringify(this.PacageListArray));
         formData.append('package_type_id', JSON.stringify(this.PackageArray));
          formData.append('budget', JSON.stringify(this.customPayArr));
          formData.append('is_manual', JSON.stringify(this.CheckAutoPayArr));
          formData.append('file', this.files);


      const token  = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');

      this.rest.newProposals(formData , token).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
      });


       }
```

Comment: check if value is present before set in form data

Comment: please show how you have defined other fields which are showing null?

Comment: @SaurabhYadav Yes Value is present before ser in formData